# Debug in Python Library with Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, scipy

I am writing a Python 3.6 program using Visual Studio 2017. Debugging my own code works fine: I can set breakpoints, examine variable values, step into functions, etc. But my program also uses scipy, and when I try to step to step into a scipy function (using F11), the debugger just moves to the next line of my own code. Scipy is itself written in Python and Python is interpreted, so I don't see why this shouldn't be possible. How I can use the Visual Studio debugger to step into a Python library function? (I have already un-checked "Just My Code" in the Debug > Options window.)

Comment: can you show us the code

Comment: from scipy import special

z = complex(-27.0, 1.0E-2)

lgz = special.loggamma(z)

print(lgz)

Comment: here, which line is getting skipped by debugger?

Comment: The only scipy invocation: special.loggamma(z). To be clear, the line is being executed, the debugger is just not stepping into the loggamma code.

Comment: i jut created a new question based on your question. So, i noticed that the files in which the logamma was defined, there was just a pass statement. and no logic inside it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849771/how-can-a-function-return-a-value-when-there-is-only-pass-inside-the-function

Comment: may be you can wait for an answer there. my guess, these are some c++ codes which create temporary python files which act like templates to execute the function

Comment: `loggamma` is compiled code (probably with `cython`, or at least using `cython` to link it).  It isn't available for debugging.  Why do you need to see inside that function?   Here's the `cython` source code: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/_loggamma.pxd

Comment: Okay, I understand. I had already found the source code, but it's often easier to understand what code is doing by stepping through it in a debugger than by reading it. After a lot of study, I did figure out what the code is doing that I hadn't expected, but I would have got to that point a lot faster in a debugger.